# Table of numbers adaptable to various widths

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

It's been a while since I asked an embarrassing question, so here is one for your amusement: I want to print a table of numbers that is able to adapt to various column sizes so can't use a `tabular` like environment.

Well, I thought that this would be straight forward and a simple solution such as to use a `\makebox[3em][r]{}` should work. And of course, I need a space on one side so that it could break at line boundaries.

And it fact it works *pretty* good, but not exactly right. So what I have below only seems to only have a problem with the last row as I get the following result with the MWE below:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand*{\ListOrPrimes}{%
      2,      3,      5,      7,     11,     13,     17,     19,     23,     29, 
     31,     37,     41,     43,     47,     53,     59,     61,     67,     71, 
     73,     79,     83,     89,     97,    101,    103,    107,    109,    113, 
    127,    131,    137,    139,    149,    151,    157,    163,    167,    173,
    179,    181,    191,    193,    197,    199,    211,    223,    227,    229
}%

\begin{document}

\noindent
The sequence of primes is:
\medskip
{\raggedright%
\par\noindent\foreach \x in \ListOrPrimes{%
        \makebox[4em][r]{\x}\space%
}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: You're missing an end-of-line `%` after `229`.

Comment: Well of course only _after_ actually posting a question does a solution present it self... :-).  I'll leave it up in case someone want to figure it out.  Yeah, what Werner said!! But why? It didn't seem to create any problems on the other entries.

Comment: The other entries all have a *preceding* space, while `229` comes with a *trailing* space. And, since you're using a `r`ight-aligned `\makebox`, only the *trailing* space of an entry is revealed this way.

Comment: Hmmm, actually although that fixes it with the MWE in my actual use case the two entries _before_ the last one exhibit the problem -- the last one aligns just fine...

Comment: How about `\makebox[4em][r]{\x\unskip}` for the definition inside `\pgffor`?

Comment: Hmmm, the `\unskip` solution still has a problem in my actual use case -- can't seem to be able to easily reproduce it in the MWE though so something else is going on...

Comment: `\x\unskip` appears to fix the MWE but the fact that it is needed lookls like a bug (or at least a quirk) in pgf's `\ListOrPrimes` macro which has no space after any of the numbers (just a comma) except the last

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use LaTeX3 facilities, the problem of leading and trailing spaces will disappear:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\printlist}{s O{4em} m}
 {
  \par\noindent
  \IfBooleanTF#1
   { \clist_map_inline:Vn #3 { \grill_print_item:nn { #2 } { ##1 } } }
   { \clist_map_inline:nn { #3 } { \grill_print_item:nn { #2 } { ##1 } } }
  \par
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_map_inline:nn { V }
\cs_new:Npn \grill_print_item:nn #1 #2
 {
  \makebox[#1][r]{#2}~
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*{\ListOfPrimes}{
      2,      3,      5,      7,     11,     13,     17,     19,     23,     29, 
     31,     37,     41,     43,     47,     53,     59,     61,     67,     71, 
     73,     79,     83,     89,     97,    101,    103,    107,    109,    113, 
    127,    131,    137,    139,    149,    151,    157,    163,    167,    173,
    179,    181,    191,    193,    197,    199,    211,    223,    227,    229
}

\begin{document}
\noindent This is a list of primes:
\printlist*{\ListOfPrimes}

\medskip

\noindent This is another:
\printlist[2em]{2,3, 5, 7}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\printlist*` you give as argument a control sequence (expanding to comma separated list); without the `*` you simply give the list. The optional argument is the width of the boxes.